# Django | formfield_for_manytomany - name display in admin

Tags: python, django

I am just learning Django, please forgive any ignorance here.

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin = models.BooleanField("Admin Status")


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Team Name", max_length=20, default="")
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="admins")
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="members")
```

Here's my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Team, Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'admin')


admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)


class TeamAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print(db_field)
        if db_field.name == "admins":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Profile.objects.filter(admin=True)
        return super(TeamAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


admin.site.register(Team, TeamAdmin)
```

This works perfect, but the admins on my admin page are showing as "Profile object (1)," "Profile object (2)," etc...

What am I doing wrong? Or where do I change the way those display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the `__str__` as names for the object, and by default that uses `Model object (pk)`. You thus can override the `__str__`, for example with:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return str(user)
```

Comment: You're brilliant!  Thank you so much!  I did have to change it to `return str(self.user)` but it worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I'm experiencing another issue.  So, I updated the return field to say, `return str(f"{obj.user.first_name} {obj.user.last_name}")`  This now displays exactly how I want, but when I try to save changes to the field, I get this error: `Field 'id' expected a number but got <Profile: Test Admin — (TestAdmin1)>.`  That's, obviously, the test user I'm trying to make admin.  It looks like I must have my "formfield_for_manytomany" set up incorrectly.